# How to remove a weakReference from a list?

Tags: java, list, weak-references

I've got a list of weakReferences to objects in java.
How do i write a method that gets the real object instance and removes it's weak reference from this list?

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a method which takes the strong object reference as a parameter?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I think you *may* want:

```
public static <T> void removeReference(List<WeakReference<T>> list,
                                       T reference)
{
    for (Iterator<WeakReference<T>> iterator = list.iterator();
         iterator.hasNext(); )
    {
        WeakReference<T> weakRef = iterator.next();
        if (weakRef.get() == reference)
        {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also remove the nulled weakrefs while you're at it

Comment: @ratchet: I wondered about that, but it depends what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: How do you remove a null element from the list? `if (weakRef.get() == null)`?

Comment: @EduardoBezerra: Yes, I would expect that to be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the Javadocs for [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). Two important things to note:
 1. it is protected, so you can extend it, and
 2. it does not override Object.equals()

So, two approaches to do what you want:

First, the simple way, use what @Jon Skeet said.

Second, more elegant way. Note: this only works if you are the only one adding to the list too:

```
public class HardReference<T> {
  private final T _object;

  public HardReference(T object) {
    assert object != null;
    _object = object;
  }

  public T get() { return _object; }

  public int hashCode() { return _object.hashCode(); }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof HardReference) {
      return get() == ((HardReference) other).get();
    }
    if (other instanceof Reference) {
      return get() == ((Reference) other).get();
    }
    return get() == other;
  }
}

class WeakRefWithEquals<T> extends WeakReference<T> {

  WeakRefWithEquals(T object) { super(object); }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof HardReference) {
      return get() == ((HardReference) other).get();
    }
    if (other instanceof Reference) {
      return get() == ((Reference) other).get();
    }
    return get() == other;
  }
}
```

Once you have these utility classes, you can wrap objects stored in Lists, Maps etc with whatever reference subclass -- like the WeakRefWithEquals example above.
When you are looking for an element, you need to wrap it HardReference, just in case the collection implementation does

```
param.equals(element)
```

instead of

```
element.equals(param)
```